# nesting JSF expression strings

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I want to achieve this using dynamic parameters for value expressions:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{someBean.someValue}" var="field">
    <h:column>#{anotherBean[field]}</h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

where `field` is `'user.name'` or `'location.address.zip'` or...

Is it possible?

Note that this is a simple example, I'm interested in `ValueExpression` not in `dataTable` component.

**UPDATE**
now the question is: how to replace standard BeanELResolver?

looking in ELUtils:

```
    ...
    composite.addRootELResolver(IMPLICIT_RESOLVER);
    composite.add(FLASH_RESOLVER);
    composite.addPropertyELResolver(COMPOSITE_COMPONENT_ATTRIBUTES_EL_RESOLVER);
    addELResolvers(composite, associate.getELResolversFromFacesConfig());
    addVariableResolvers(composite, FacesCompositeELResolver.ELResolverChainType.Faces,
            associate);
    addPropertyResolvers(composite, associate);
    composite.add(associate.getApplicationELResolvers());
    composite.addRootELResolver(MANAGED_BEAN_RESOLVER);
    composite.addPropertyELResolver(RESOURCE_RESOLVER);
    composite.addPropertyELResolver(BUNDLE_RESOLVER);
    ...
```

but i don't fully understand resolver chain yet... so i'll go studying :)

**UPDATE 2**

this code works ;)

```
public class ExtendedBeanELResolver extends BeanELResolver
{
    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) throws NullPointerException, PropertyNotFoundException, ELException
    {
        try
        {
            return super.getValue(context, base, property);
        }
        catch(PropertyNotFoundException e)
        {
            try
            {
                Object value = base;

                for(String part : property.toString().split("\\."))
                {
                    value = super.getValue(context, value, part);
                }

                return value;
            }
            catch(PropertyNotFoundException e1)
            {
                context.setPropertyResolved(false);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: no, i'm saying right: `public List<String> getSomeValue() { ... }`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is by default not supported. You need a custom `ELResolver` here. Easiest is to extend the existing [`BeanELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/BeanELResolver.html).

Here's a kickoff example:

```
public class ExtendedBeanELResolver extends BeanELResolver {

    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property)
        throws NullPointerException, PropertyNotFoundException, ELException
    {
        if (property == null || base == null || base instanceof ResourceBundle || base instanceof Map || base instanceof Collection) {
            return null;
        }

        String propertyString = property.toString();

        if (propertyString.contains(".")) {
            Object value = base;

            for (String propertyPart : propertyString.split("\\.")) {
                value = super.getValue(context, value, propertyPart);
            }

            return value;
        }
        else {
            return super.getValue(context, base, property);
        }
    }

}
```

To get it to run, register it as follows in `faces-config.xml`:

```xml
<application>
    <el-resolver>com.example.ExtendedBeanELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for to solve this and some other little thing. thanks @BalusC, you save me so much time that you deserve part of my salary ;)

Comment: however declaring it in `faces-config.xml` overrides default `CompositeELResolver`. how to replace standard `BeanELResolver` in `CompositeELResolver.elResolvers`?

Comment: oops, i was wrong. it does not override, but get inserted before. see question update.

Comment: What problem exactly did it cause for you? The change should be transparent as it consistently delegates to the super.

Comment: causes `PropertyNotFoundException` trying to read bundles properties. however doc states _Because this resolver handles base objects of any type, it should be placed near the end of a composite resolver. Otherwise, it will claim to have resolved a property before any resolvers that come after it get a chance to test if they can do so as well._ so i solved this catching `PropertyNotFoundException` and setting `context.setPropertyResolved(false);`

Comment: Right. Add a line `if (base instanceof ResourceBundle) return null;` to top. You might want to do the same for `Map` and `Collection`. I edited the example.

Comment: @BalusC I saw that we can add multiple `<el-resolver>` in one single `faces-config.xml` (two for exmaple), in that case how would JSF now which one to use (assuming that each resolver is for a specific kind of expressions)? I tried to make it as an independent question but doesn't seem to me a big matter, so I said maybe you could give me some hint that I can follow. Thanks in advance

Comment: @Tarik: they follow decorator pattern (like `InputStream` and friends). The one registered later wraps/delegates to the previously registered one via `super.xxx()` call.

Answer (score 4):

The work made on this topic is very interesting, but not complete.

In case you pass value in a Composite Component, which is set in this component, it doesn't work.

Example :

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="value" type="java.lang.Boolean" required="true"  />
</composite:interface>
<composite:implementation>
        <h:inputText id="inputValue" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" 
        </h:inputText>
</composite:implementation>
```

With the ExtendedBeanElResolver, it throws a PropertyNotFoundException when I set value.

So, I spend few hours to find a solution, and here is the working solution, to be able to use the ExtendedBeanElResolver with the ability to set values inside composite components :

```
public class ExtendedBeanELResolver extends BeanELResolver {

    private static final String PRIMEFACES_RESOURCE_PREFIX = "primefaces:";
    private static final String RESOURCES_HANDLER = "class org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.GraphicResourceHandler";
    private static final String PRIMEFACES_EXT_RESOURCES_HANDLER = "class org.primefaces.extensions.application.PrimeFacesExtensionsResourceHandler";

    @Override
    public Object getValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property) {

            if (property == null || base == null || base instanceof ResourceBundle || base instanceof Map || base instanceof Collection
                    || property.toString().startsWith(PRIMEFACES_RESOURCE_PREFIX) || base.getClass().toString().equals(RESOURCES_HANDLER)
                    || base.getClass().toString().equals(PRIMEFACES_EXT_RESOURCES_HANDLER)) {
                return null;
            }
            String propertyString = property.toString();
            if (propertyString.contains(".")) {
                Object value = base;

                for (String propertyPart : propertyString.split("\\.")) {
                    value = super.getValue(context, value, propertyPart);
                }

                return value;
            } else {
                Object v = super.getValue(context, base, property);
               return v;
            }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(ELContext context, Object base, Object property, Object val) {
        if (base != null && !(base instanceof ResourceBundle) && !(base instanceof Map) && !(base instanceof Collection))
            super.setValue(context, base, property, val);
    }
}
```

(I added the "setValue" part).

And now it works. Don't hesitate to give me your feedback, as this is my first post in this website !