# Can multiple EL resolver use in JSF 2.0?

Tags: java, jsf-2, el

I would like to know about EL resolvers in JSF. Can we use multiple EL resolvers in a project?. Let's say, If I use Spring's `DelegatingVariableResolver`, can I add another EL resolver like Seam's `SeamELResolver`?

My expectation is, `DelegatingVariableResolver` delegate another EL resolver when he get an error or exception during translating process.

Comment: Looks like it is possible to have multiple el resolvers according to this jboss community [thread](https://community.jboss.org/thread/184555) by extending [CompositeELResolver](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/CompositeELResolver.html) unless you have the same criteria that the original OP is having trouble with having custom el resolver at the desired place.

Comment: May be this is helpful.http://techblog.bozho.net/?p=165

Comment: @SRy absolutely correct.
CycDemo look at BalusC answering my question: [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10695696/2911357)

Answer (score 0):

DelegatingVariableResolver  is deprecated since Spring 3.2, then yes you could declare multiple ElResolver as :

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>     
    <el-resolver>com.agitech.erp.bean.BeanResolver</el-resolver>    
  <locale-config>
   <default-locale>fr</default-locale>
  </locale-config>
 </application>
public class BeanResolver extends javax.el.ELResolver {
........
}
```

if you use MyFaces you can choose the way that the custom resolvers are ordered with

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.EL_RESOLVER_COMPARATOR</param-name>
    <param-value>org.apache.myfaces.el.unified.CustomLastELResolverComparator</param-value>
</context-param>
```