# Trying to nest JSF expression strings

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, el

I'd like to know whether it is possible to adapt the *ExtendedBeanELResolver* from the question [nesting-jsf-expression-strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694311/nesting-jsf-expression-strings) as well to handle this nested EL expression:

```
#{controllerBean.getBean('userProfileBean', component).street}*
```

whereby *controllerBean.getBean* returns the bean *userProfileBean*. I'll get with the *ExtenedBeanELResolver* following exception:

```
SCHWERWIEGEND: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /WEB-INF/templates/modification/userProfile.xhtml @35,196 value="#{controllerBean.getBean('userProfileBean', component).street}": Property 'getBean' not found on type com.something.ControllerBean
```

If I insert additional brackets it works, but looks even more ugly than now:

```
#{(controllerBean.getBean('userProfileBean', component)).street}*
```

Is it possible to do without the additional brackets?

**UPDATE 1 after CycDemo's answer:**

Strange problem.
If i put the

```
<h:inputText value="#{beanOne.getBean('data').title}" />
```

**inside** a form the page renders, but only until i submit the form. After that the same error will be shown.

```
WARNUNG: /WEB-INF/templates/home.xhtml @61,66 value="#{beanOne.getBean('data').title}": Property 'getBean' not found on type com.something.BeanOne
```

If i change it to

```
<p:inputText value="#{beanOne.getBean('data').title}" />
```

the page won't even render in the beginning.
I think the problem is that the JSF is trying to call the setter when the form is submitted but can't evaluate it correctly.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2**

Appearently JSF is trying to call *getGetBean()* because it is looking for a **property** on *BeanOne* (I had a breakpoint there in eclipse) which is wrong:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class BeanOne {

  private Object bean = new String("something");

  public Object getBean(String name) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    return context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context,
        "#{" + name + "}",
        Object.class);
  }

  public Object getGetBean() {
    return bean; // <-- will be called by JSF
  }

  public void setGetBean(Object bean) {
    this.bean = bean;
  }

}
```

Comment: which error you get again? submit your cause;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure

```
    #{(controllerBean.getBean('userProfileBean', component)).street}
    change to
    #{controllerBean.getBean('userProfileBean', component).street}
```

It is work in JSF 2.0 when I test.

Use `jboss-el`. Download jar file [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.jboss.el&version=2.0.0.GA&searchType=bundlesByName&searchQuery=expression)

BeanOne.java
    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

```
@ManagedBean(name="BeanOne")
@RequestScoped
public class BeanOne {
    private Data data;

    public Data getBean(String title) {
        data = new Data(title);
        return data;
    }
    public void show() {
        System.out.println("User Input ==>" + data.getInput());
    }
}
```

Date.java

```
public class Data {
    private String title;
    private String input;

    public Data(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getInput() {
        return input;
    }

    public void setInput(String input) {
        this.input = input;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

pageOne.xtml

```
<h:form>
    <h:inputText value="#{BeanOne.getBean('Test').input}"/><br/>
    <h:commandButton value="Show" action="#{BeanOne.show}"/>
</h:form>
```

add the following configuration in web.xml

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

Comment: @Manuel, Please, check my answer I updated for your new question, again.

Comment: Try to make your *Data* class a managed bean, and fetch it like I did with your *BeanOne*. You should get the same error as I did.

Comment: I think there is a "return data" missing in your *BeanOne*'s method *getBean(String title)*.