# How to pass EL argument in method?

Tags: jsf, el

I have just a question in passing parameters on backing beans method.

I would like pass an EL value between a method parameters like:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="somsgroup" value="#{store_itemController.filter_sgroup}">
   <f:selectItems value="#{commonDataFunctions.getItemByName('store_sgroup', 'id', 'title', '[tb:store_sgroup][fd:title]=${store_itemController.filter_group}', '[tb:store_sgroup][fd:title]', true)}"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

it seems like `${store_itemController.filter_group}` it is not translated because the method receives `${store_itemController.filter_group}` just like a string.

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed not nest EL expressions this way. EL expressions can only be inlined.

You can use `<c:set>` to create a new variable wherein the desired expression is inlined in the desired value and then reuse this variable as argument of another EL expression.

```html
xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
...
<c:set var="filterGroup" value="[tb:store_sgroup][fd:title]=#{store_itemController.filter_group}" scope="request" />
...
<f:selectItems value="#{commonDataFunctions.getItemByName('store_sgroup', 'id', 'title', filterGroup, '[tb:store_sgroup][fd:title]', true)}"/>
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried and this solutions is the perfect workaround for this JSF missing. Thank a lot !!!!

Comment: Balus, when I view the page, I can print my param - <p>testting: #{item.id}</p> param is passed ok, and also it is good in ui:repeat and renders content

<ui:repeat value="#{adresarService.getAdresarById(item.id)}" var="it">

But when I update my form with submit, it doesen save and doesent render page. What to do?

Comment: @DarioBB: Make sure it's view scoped. It's re-checked during submit.

Comment: BalusC, doesen't work either. I mean, it works when listed, but when i hit sumbit button, view crashes and there is no source code. And if I put real number instead parameter idem.id, like 453 - that won't happen - page is successfully rendered after submit and data is also successfully saved to db. I realised in logs that it is because on page submit parameter item.id is 0, and no 0 value is found in db, so Hibernate chrashes. How to solve that..can it be avoided if item.id is 0? Can't figure out why is JSF doing that on submit

Comment: p.s. this is from console log where I realised what am I talking about in previous comment:

WARNING: /items_promjena.xhtml @35,78 value="#{adresarService.getAdresarById(item.id)}": org.hibernate.ObjectNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists: [com.dev.user.model.Adresar#0]

Answer (score -1):

I would like to suggest to use `JBoss EL`. If so, you need to configure as below in `web.xml`.
Download jar file [here](http://ebr.springsource.com/repository/app/bundle/version/detail?name=com.springsource.org.jboss.el&version=2.0.0.GA&searchType=bundlesByName&searchQuery=expression) and reference for [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12929488/trying-to-nest-jsf-expression-strings/12929672#12929672).

```
<context-param>     
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

Comment: That doesn't add support for nesting EL expressions at all. Did you read the question beyond the title?

Comment: @BalusC, you mean `JBoss EL` doesn't support `EL` sing with `$`?

Comment: No. EL does not support nested expressions. In the future, better run and experiment it yourself first before posting an answer.