# How does JSF access HashMap values in the view?

Tags: jsf-2, hashmap, el

Which methodology is JSF using to access `HashMap` values in the view? I know the way to get `HashMap` value by using the EL Expression `#{bean.map.key}`, but I am curious as to how it works under the covers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not part of JSF. This is part of EL. EL has some default [resolvers](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/ELResolver.html). One of them is the [`MapELResolver`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/el/MapELResolver.html). You can of course homebrew your own and register it via `<application><el-resolver>`.

Comment: Thanks BalusC :) Can you plz guide me with links to have my own resolvers.

Comment: Just implement `ELResolver` class or subclass according its contract (click the link to see the javadoc) and register it as `<el-resolver>` in `faces-config.xml`. You can find an example in those answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9327479/how-do-i-use-a-java-util-set-with-uidata-in-jsf-specifically-hdatatable/9327572#9327572 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694311/nesting-jsf-expression-strings/10695696#10695696

Comment: Thanks again BalusC :) I ll try out this... using the above links