# Access nested properties in variable EL expression

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, seam, el

Normally, I can access nested bean's property, in this case, `address_name` of `address` like this:

```
#{customer.address.address_name}
```

Let's say, I have a String:

```
String addressPath = address.address_name
```

How can I access `address_name` with `#{customer}` and `#{addressPath}`?

I tried

```
#{customer[addressPath]}
```

But it only works with direct property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nesting JSF expression strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10694311/nesting-jsf-expression-strings)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if exists a standard way to do this... but I use to create a method into "costumer" bean (or a helper bean in scope) to evaluate programmatically the EL expression dinamically.

You could implement a method like this:

```
    public class Costumer{
        ...
            public Object eval(String exp) {
               //Concatenate your bean name or do it before method call instead
               //to get a String with a content like: "customer.address.address_name"
               exp = "customer." + exp;
        
               FacesContext facesContext = getFacesContext();
               Application appContext = facesContext.getApplication();
               ExpressionFactory expFactory = appContext.getExpressionFactory();
               ELContext expContext = facesContext.getELContext();
               ValueExpression valExp = expFactory.createValueExpression(expContext,exp, Object.class);
    
               return valExp.getValue(expContext);
             }
       ...
    }
```

And then you only need to call this method with something like this:

`#{customer.eval(addressPath)}` or  `#{customer.eval(myScopedBean.addressPath)}`

I think that exist better solutions and maybe your JSF framework or component's library (seam, primefaces, richfaces, omnifaces, etc) has a method to do something like this.